# How to get Regex for TDs in a TR

Tags: c#, html, regex, html-table

I need help with regualar expressions. (using c#)

In the html-sourcecode i got something like this.

```
[...]
<TR class=tblDataGreyNH>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; FONT-WEIGHT: bold" class=tblHeader>Total Time </TD>
<TD>07:47 </TD>
<TD>04:48 </TD>
<TD>00:00 </TD>
<TD>00:00 </TD>
<TD>07:42 </TD>
<TD>00:00 </TD>
<TD>00:00 </TD></TR>
[..]
<TR class=tblDataGreyNH nowrap>
<TD>Total </TD>
<TD>20:17 </TD></TR>
<TR style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold" class=tblDataWhiteNH nowrap>
<TD>Total Time </TD>
<TD width=75>20:17 </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD colSpan=3>
...
```

The classnames are always the same.
I need all the TD's parsed into a stringarray.
tblDataGreyNH is the importants class.

here is the whole table, where the td's are inside. (if some you need)

```
<table class="tblList">
<form action="/interface/timesheet/ViewUserTimeSheet.php" method="get" name="timesheet"></form>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr class="tblHeader">
<tr class="tblHeader">
<tr class="tblDataWhiteNH">
<tr class="tblDataWhiteNH">
<tr class="tblHeader">
<tr class="tblDataGreyNH">
<td class="tblHeader" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right"> Total Time </td>
<td> 07:47 </td>
<td> 04:48 </td>
<td> 00:00 </td>
<td> 00:00 </td>
<td> 07:42 </td>
<td> 00:00 </td>
<td> 00:00 </td>
</tr>
<tr class="tblDataWhiteNH">
<tr class="tblHeader">
<tr valign="top">
</tbody>
</table>
```

I hope there is someone who can help me with this problem.
Regex seems impossible to understand for me.
I can't grasp the basics with that ReGeX stuff!? :/

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Regex for HTML, I would suggest checking out the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Very simple:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("...your sample html...");

// all <td> tags in the document
foreach (HtmlNode td in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td")) 
{
     Console.WriteLine(td.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use regex to parse HTML (one of many refs: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not))

There exists a great .NET library named HtmlAgilityPack that I would recommend.